# get session cookie content when cookie is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get the session cookies content since I need to process it with javascript.

This usually works fine - but not when the session cookie is being set (first page load).

```
session_key_name = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
cookie_value = cookies[session_key_name]
```

How can I get the value that will be set to the session cookie on the first page load?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not find an answer to this. My work around is to detect on the front page if the user already sends a cookie. If not I will redirect to another page where I either output a message that cookies are not enabled or the user is redirected to the start page.